# Spring controller exception handling locally and globally

Tags: spring, exceptionhandler

I would like some advice on how to achieve the following. I'm not providing code, as my problem is theoretical, but upon request I can. So this is the situation:

- I have multiple controllers, each can throw XYException
- I have a @ControllerAdvice class, in which I have an @ExceptionHandler watching for XYExceptions. When it happens, it prints out "XY".
- In one (and only one) controller, when XYException is thrown, I want to do some additional task (let's say, do something that only that controller can do), and then I want the exception to be "passed on" to the global handler mentioned above.

I know I can catch the exception, do the desired task in catch block, and then re-throw the exception so the global handler can catch it, but what if I have 23 methods in the controller potentially throwing XYExceptions, and I do not want to put try-catch blocks in all 23 methods.

What is the clean Spring way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `AOP` to achieve that. You'd write a method that intercepts the method inside that controller and when they throw an exception, you're `aop` method would run and you can do your stuff and then the exception would go in your handler class.

To achieve that you should have a class and anotate it with `@Aspect` and `@Component`
then have a method anotated with `@AfterThrowing` and setting the pointcut which will intercept when the given method throws an exception.

Look into Aspect Oriented Programming and `Aspectj` for more info.

Comment: Thanks, I know AOP, but I've never actually used it. I did look into it, and it seems that it will solve my problem. Funny thing however, that on the very day I posted this (and read your response), I could not make it work. I left the project for three weeks, came back today, and now it seems working (only logging though, but that means it's working).

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to handle this case in `ControllerAdvice` is checking the stacktrace where the exception originated.

```
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
public String handleExc(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, Exception e) {
    if ( /*Have all null and safe check */ e.getStackTrace()[0].contains("MyController")) {
        // Do your exception handling
    }
}
```